# is there any solution if div container 'display:flex' not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers

It might be my own mistake or carelessness during following a Video tutorial in purpose of learning in youtube where when in the part on the home page content, I want the content of a picture and text to be inline like the tutorial but mine were like this

[image]

So I decided to learn about `display: flex` where we put in the parents Division to flex the two content division inside it
How I want it to look like

[image]

HTML:

[image]

CSS:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). **IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT A SUITABLE REPLACEMENT**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set .main-slide as display:flex and flex direction: row and wrap the content except the image in a div with a class .left-div for example which will be display:block. If the screen width is small they may not align in a row anymore.

```css
.main-slide {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  }
  .left-div{
    display:block;
  }
  .main-slide div:nth-child(2){
    display:  flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }

  .main-slide div:nth-child(1){
    padding-top: 20px;
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .main-slide div:nth-child(1) p{
    padding: 20px 0;

  }

  .main-slide div:nth-child(1) span{
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-offset: 10px;
    text-decoration-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="main-slide">
    <div class="left-div">
      <h1>enjoy<span>delicious food</span>in your healthy life</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Pariatur, esse autem ducimus explicabo consectetur nam temporibus voluptatem quia obcaecatinisi
        rerum sunt dolorem dicta harum eum eveniet ipsam quam natus?
      </p>
      <button class="red-btn">Visit now <span>&#8594;</span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="right-div">
      <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71pqfvJKW5L.__AC_SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I add it to my code but it still not solving my problem, is there any other solution you have in mind? do you need anything like the detailed of the code I can provide it

Comment: I think the best way is to use css grid layout.  Will try to post it later. You can also keep that way and resize the image and text  according to screen size to make it responsive and still aligned

Comment: if you want you can remove the above .main-slide class and add this css code with grid layout and hope this help and pls let me know if you need anything else                          .main-slide {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  }

  .left-div h1{
    font-size: clamp(15px,2.5vw,3rem);
  }

  .left-div p{
    font-size: clamp(12px,2vw,2.5rem);
  }

  .main-slide .right-div img {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
  }

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna use flex dispaly you must wrap all of your code in flex with an  row direction -> flex-direction: row; , then in right div place your image , in left div set flex-direction: column and write other code like your text or etc... , and set flex :1 to those to get same width

small exmaple:

```
  <div style={{display : 'flex' , flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <div style={{display : 'flex',flex :1 , flexDirection : 'column' }}>
                    {/* your text here  
                    <p>txt 1</p>
                    <p>txt 2</p> */}

                  </div>
                  <div style={{flex :1, display : 'flex'}} >
                    {/* your image here  
                    <img src=""/> */}

                  </div>
              </div>
```